# Change all category page layouts to one column in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, layout

How do I change all category page layouts to one column, no layered navigation, no compared products, no recently viewed products on sidebar, etc.?

**NOTE:** I want to achieve scope with XML layout not from admin; I know admin stuff.

How do I achieve the above scope?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Update your catalog.xml with the below code.

```
<catalog_category_default>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>
```

I hope this will work for you.